# superconductor levitating in earth's magnetic field?

Tags: superconductivity, geomagnetism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can superconducting magnets fly (or repel the earth's core)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14044/can-superconducting-magnets-fly-or-repel-the-earths-core)

I've seen superconductors levitating on magnets. But is it possible for superconductors to levitate on Earth from Earth's magnetic field?

Comment: Another duplicate that is arguably better written than the original. Certainly the answer here is superior. Any thoughts from on merging them or leaving them separate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [lift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_levitation#Lift) generated by magnetic field *B* on a superconductor of area *S* is:

\begin{equation}
F = \frac{B^2S}{2\mu_0}
\end{equation}

disregarding lateral forces and assuming superconducting cylinder (or similar shape) with area *S* at the top and bottom and height *h*, we need three forces to remain in the equilibrium: magnetic pressure on top, bottom and gravity force:

\begin{equation}
F_{b} - F_{t} = F_{g}
\end{equation}

denoting density of the superconductor as *ρ*, Earth' gravity as *g* and magnetic field at the top and bottom of the object as B<sub>t</sub> and B<sub>b</sub>, we have

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2\mu_0}(B_{b}^2-B_{t}^2)=\rho gh
\end{equation}

assuming the vertical rate of change of magnetic field is nearly constant and denoting the average magnetic field as *B*, we have

\begin{equation}
-B\frac{dB}{dz}=\mu_{0}\rho g
\end{equation}

Compare with [diamagnetic levitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_levitation#Direct_diamagnetic_levitation) (superconductor's magnetic susceptibility is -1).

Now, [Earth magnetic field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field#Intensity) is between 25 to 65 *μT*. For the derivative I have found [this survey from British Columbia](http://www.em.gov.bc.ca/Mining/Geoscience/MapPlace/Documents/Geophysics/Toodoggone/of4608_10.pdf) with upper point on the scale being 2.161 *nT/m*. Assuming this to be the maximum for vertical derivative we get the required density of **1.1394e-08 *kg/m<sup>3</sup>***. For comparison air density at the sea level at 15C is around 1.275 *kg/m<sup>3</sup>*, so required density is 8 orders of magnitude smaller.

Even assuming a very high vertical derivative where *B* goes from its maximum 65 *μT* to 0 on 1 *m* of height results in density required of **0.00034272 *kg/m<sup>3</sup>***.

Comment: so it's possible for levitation if the superconductor has maximal area and minimal density? What about metallic hydrogen? I hear that it is the lightest metal in the universe. Though I can't find any numbers....

Comment: Well, you certainly couldn't keep on decreasing the thickness beyond London penetration depth.

Comment: thats like in the nm right? Which would be enough in terms of thickness for levitation.

Comment: since a sheet so thin would break easily, it should theoretically work in the same way if instead I had superconductor powder. I'm assuming that each particle is like a very small thin square sheet, so given the right density, these particles can levitate under gravity, even when in close proximity to each other. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: just saw your update about the magnetic field obstacle. so in effect, given the perfect material, levitation cannot be achieved practically? quite a shame....

Comment: I have redone the calculations to account for the "obstacle". Unfortunately, it becomes practically impossible. Shame indeed ;-)

Comment: at that density you calculated, anything(quantum effects or not) can pretty much just float in the air :/ I guess there must be some type of direct magnetic field generated by something to get this to work instead.

Comment: 0.00034272 kg/m3 is actually 0.34272 g / (m^3). Lithium has a density of .53g/m^3, and metallic hydrogen most definitely is less that 0.34. So if we were to go by your optimistic model, then metallic hydrogen would levitate, where as your other much smaller estimate would most likely not. I wish I knew what the density of metallic hydrogen is....too bad 65uT to 0 is not exactly common place on Earth....

Comment: wiki says that Hydrogen's density at melt point is .07g/m^3 so that means that dB/dz is gonna be from 13uT to 0 on 1m of height, still impossible in nature it seems....maybe the poles might work out

Comment: Liquid hydrogen has density of 67.8kg/m^3=67800 g/m^3. Far too much.

Comment: what if we attach a cone that redirects and focuses the magnetic field on the superconductor? Does that count as increasing dB/dz ?? If we have a theoretically infinitely large cone, we could probably provide enough magnetic field strength for levitation.

Comment: I think people are missing here that we are talking about smaller densities than air has, so it will levitate because the low density anyways, just like zeppelins.