# Is it possible to combine aerogels and superconductors? would it levitate?

Tags: gravity, superconductivity

I read a previous question ["superconductor levitating in earth's magnetic field?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17137/superconductor-levitating-in-earths-magnetic-field)
it seemed like the impact of gravity would make this unikely unless the superconductor was super light.

Is it conceivable to combine the properties of aerogels and superconductors to create light material that repels the earth's field?

basically is the synthesis even possible? and if so what might it require?